# Javalin Migration

Tags: kotlin, jackson, javalin

I am new to Kotlin and Javalin. While migrating from Javalin 3 to 4, `Javalinjackson.configure()` function is deprecated. Below is the part of the code

```
import io.javalin.plugin.json.JavalinJackson
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.jacksonObjectMapper

val om = jacksonObjectMapper().apply { registerModule(JavaTimeModule()) }
JavalinJackson.configure(om)
```

I read in the documentation is that `config.jsonMapper()` is used now. Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JavalinJackson` is not a singleton any more. To "configure" it just pass your `ObjectMapper` as a constructor parameter:

```kotlin
val om = jacksonObjectMapper().apply { registerModule(JavaTimeModule()) }
val jacksonMapper = JavalinJackson(om)
```

and then pass resulting instance of `JsonMapper` into Javalin config:

```kotlin
val app = Javalin.create { config: JavalinConfig ->
    config.jsonMapper(jacksonMapper)
}.start()
```